# How can I manipulate JSON data into javascript and display onto HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am trying to take JSON data from my server and manipulate the price to do comparisons. I believe JavaScript is the correct language but I could be wrong.

[image]

I would be taking an input from a form on html to switch between "Shell" and "ARCO" and could also add the location's total cost and be able to use that in other functions.

Can I put the individual items into a variable that can be changed over time?

Thanks!

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: @Confused: There is no need for jQuery if you just want to parse JSON.

Comment: Sure, it's completely possible. JavaScript has built-in support for parsing JSON and has access to the DOM.

Comment: Yes you can! `var data = JSON.parse(yourJson);` And use data as associative array

Answer (score 0):

I will answer that according to how i have understood the question, and that is reading Data from a json file so as to use it in a html page.

```
//This is our Ajax function to load the JSON data
 function ajaxLoad(path,callback){
 try{
 var response;
 var xmlhttp =new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if(this.readyState==4&&this.status==200) {
 response=this.responseText;
 callback(response);
 }
 }

 xmlhttp.open("POST",path,true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 xmlhttp.send();

}
catch(e){
alert(e.message);
}
 }

//now load the data
var itemsData;
var shellProds=[];
var arcoProds=[];

ajaxLoad("Items.json",function(data){
itemsData=JSON.parse(data);
for(i in itemsData.items){try{
if(itemsData.items[i].location=="shell"){
shellProds[i].itemid=itemsData.items[i].itemid;
shellProds[i].name=itemsData.items[i].name;
shellProds[i].price=itemsData.items[i].price;
}else{

arcoProds[i].itemid=itemsData.items[i].itemid;
arcoProds[i].name=itemsData.items[i].name;
arcoProds[i].price=itemsData.items[i].price;
} 

//now you have loaded the data.
}
catch(e){
alert(e.message);

}
}
});
```

So now you have two object arrays with the loaded data.